# Something is wrong with my plist file? But what is it?

Tags: iphone, plist

Could someone please help me figure out what is wrong with my program, AND HOW O FIX IT!?

`Warning: The Copy Bundle Resources build phase contains this target's Info.plist file 'SECRET-Info.plist'.`

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Info.plist file mustn't be checked as a member of a target.